# Removing stop words from a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tokenize

```
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('stopwords')
import datetime
import numpy as np
import re
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd' 
import pandas as pd 
# Read data from file 'filename.csv' 
# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
data = pd.read_csv("march20_21.csv") 
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
#drop NA rows
data.dropna()
#drop all columns not needed
droppeddata = data.drop(columns=['created_at'])
#drop NA rows
alldata = droppeddata.dropna()

ukdata = alldata[alldata.place.str.contains('England')]
ukdata.drop(columns=['place'])

ukdata['text'].apply(word_tokenize)
eng_stopwords = stopwords.words('english')
```

I know there is a lot of redundant variables, but im still working on gettig it working before going back to refine it.

I am unsure on how to remove the stopwords, stored in the variable, from the tokenised columns. Any help is appreciated, I am brand new to Python! Thanks.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any such destructive edits will be reverted. Please see [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221) for more information on how deleting content works on this site.

Answer (score 2):

1. after applying a function to a column you need to assign the result back to the column, it's not an in-place operation.
2. after tokenization `ukdata['text']` holds a `list` of words, so you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in the apply to remove the stop words.

```
ukdata['text'] = ukdata['text'].apply(word_tokenize)
eng_stopwords = stopwords.words('english') 
ukdata['text'] = ukdata['text'].apply(lambda words: [word for word in words if word not in eng_stopwords])
```

---

Minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

eng_stopwords = stopwords.words('english') 
ukdata = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["This is a sentence."]})

ukdata['text'] = ukdata['text'].apply(word_tokenize)
ukdata['text'] = ukdata['text'].apply(lambda words: [word for word in words if word not in eng_stopwords])
```

Comment: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

I get this error when I add your code, I'm not sure what has went wrong?

Comment: hm, this is strange as I don't see any slices in you code. What if you change `ukdata['text'] = ...` to `ukdata.loc[:,'text'] = ...` in both assignments?

Comment: BTW, in all your drop operations you'll have to either assign the result back to the dataframe or use `inplace=True`

Comment: Hi Stef, I have tried this change and I get the same error unfortunatley.

Comment: very strange, does the example I added to the answer work for you?. What is your pandas version (`pd.__version__`)?

Comment: Panda version is 1.2.1. I have sent a screenshot here https://snipboard.io/lNm3gU.jpg

Comment: obviously further up your code you did some slicing in creating ukdata that you didn't show in your question. I guess the minimal example I provided doesn't print a warning. So you'll have to examine you code how you create the dataframes and read the suggested doc link from the warning message.